# trying to hook up UILabels and IBActions in a custom class (Xcode 5)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am having issues making UILabels and IBAction buttons in custom classes. Xcode seems to not want me to do it. They way I'm trying to do it is through interface builder (storyboard). I have no issue clicking and dragging to make IBOutlets and IBActions using the main View Controller but when I click and drag over to connect them in a custom class it does nothing. Am I only able to make these in the View Controller? I've attached a pic of me trying to drag over to connect my button in the custom class and you can see that nothing pops up. So basically, Are labels, buttons, text fields etc, for the View Controller class only? Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within interface builder, you will need to make sure your view controller is using your custom class by opening utilities view on the RHS of the IB, selecting the third icon along (please see picture below) and enter your custom class name in the space provided.

[image]

Your custom class will need to be a subclass of **`UIViewController`** though, like the picture below, not an `NSObject` for example.

I'm referring to this line within your .h file ...

```
@interface MyCustomClassViewController : UIViewController
```

Your custom class needs to match the UI object you are connecting it with. For example if you had `UIView` object, your custom class would need to be a subclass of `UIView`, a `UINavigationViewController` object, a subclass of `UINavigationController` etc etc.

I hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select your view controller in the stoyboard and go to the identity inspector, make sure the name there is your custom class name.